# p0v3 app service plan option doesn't show for Java 8 + JBOSS EAP 7 on portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am trying to find the p0v3 app service plan for stack java 8 + RedHat JBoss EAP 7, but portal doesn't show the option to select for region east us. Is there any limitation ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select P0V3 service plan, click on ***Explore Pricing Plans*** in `App Services=>Pricing Plan`.

[image]

- It will redirect to the service plans page, and you can select the plan as per your requirement:

[image]

[image]

But as per my observation, ***JBOSSEAP does not support on Premium0V3***  this seems to be a limitation: when I tried to create the web app, I got the below error as `the offering JBOSSEAP is not supported on Premium0V3`:

[image]

I could create web app having the same features[Java8+ JBOSS EAP 7] with ***Premium1V3 plan***.

[image]